# Is there a standard on this site to put proper names in italics?

Tags: discussion

I've been reading through a few of the questions on *The Lord of the Rings* and *The Hobbit*, and in many of them character and place names are rendered in italic type. I've never seen this usage anywhere else, but it's so common here it seems to be some kind of standard.

Comment: Wow, and I thought I was pretty much the only one to do that.

Comment: Its a way to differentiating a quote or film title or Important text from the remaining text. Its more an OP's or editors prefrense rather then standard. Some even use Bold for the same reason too.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, I'm not talking about titles, I'm talking about people's names. It's weird, but strangely common on this site.

Comment: @TRiG *Important text* covers character name too. Oops i also used italic here ;)

Answer (score 4):

No, its just something that a few users do by their own personal preference.

Comment: It seems very weird, and most distracting, but huh, each to his own, I suppose.

Comment: @TRiG Yet it is much better than either not being able to differetiate movie titles from running text or putting ugly "s in there. Yet I guess my way of using it for every kind of proper name might be a bit overkill. Still I like to recognize proper names easily. But like you said, to each his own and I don't usually change an OP's way of doing it when editing a post (apart from movie titles).

Comment: Italicising names of works is normal, @ChristianRau. Standard practise. Italicising names of people and places within those works is *weird*. (But you're definitely not the only person I've seen doing it.)

Comment: True, but you also italicise words or names that you would like to emphasize, not just titles